# 404.html template causing twig_error_syntax

Tags: templating, error-message, 404-page, error-templates

I created a generic 404.html template to replace the default Craft page. I'm getting the following error when forcing a 404 in browser. Any idea what the issue is?

```
Twig_Error_Syntax

The filter "match" does not exist. Did you mean "batch" in "404" at line 4 (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php:573)

#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(437): Twig_ExpressionParser->getFilterNodeClass('match', 4)
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(422): Twig_ExpressionParser->parseFilterExpressionRaw(Object(Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(287): Twig_ExpressionParser->parseFilterExpression(Object(Twig_Node_Expression_GetAttr))
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(179): Twig_ExpressionParser->parsePostfixExpression(Object(Twig_Node_Expression_Name))
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(84): Twig_ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression()
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php(41): Twig_ExpressionParser->getPrimary()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/TokenParser/If.php(38): Twig_ExpressionParser->parseExpression()
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Parser.php(187): Twig_TokenParser_If->parse(Object(Twig_Token))
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Parser.php(95): Twig_Parser->subparse(NULL, false)
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(507): Twig_Parser->parse(Object(Twig_TokenStream))
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(559): Twig_Environment->parse(Object(Twig_TokenStream))
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(334): Twig_Environment->compileSource('{% extends "_la...', '404')
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(292): Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('404')
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(220): Twig_Environment->render('404', Array)
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('404', Array)
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php(190): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('404', Array)
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\TemplatesController->actionRenderError()
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#20 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('renderError')
#21 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(331): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#22 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(204): CErrorHandler->render('error', Array)
#23 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/etc/errors/ErrorHandler.php(113): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#24 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(129): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#25 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(732): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#26 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#27 {main}
```

Template code causing issue:

```
{!-- META TITLE --}
<title>
    {% if entry.metaTitle != '' %}
        {{entry.metaTitle}}
    {% else %}
        My Site
    {% endif %}
</title>

{!-- META DESCRPTION --}
{% if entry.metaDescription != '' %}
<meta name="description" content="{{ entry.metaDescription }}">
{% endif %}

{!-- META KEYWORDS --}
{% if entry.metaKeywords != '' %}
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ entry.metaKeywords }}">
{% endif %}
```

Here's my `_layout.html`:

```
{% include 'global/head.html' %}    

<body>
    <div class="side-push">
        <div id="wrapper">
            {% include 'global/header.html' %}  
                {% block home_slider %}
                {% endblock %}
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            {% include 'global/footer.html' %}      
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html:

```
    <header id="header">
        <div class="header-top">
            <span class="slogan">Family Owned Since 1924</span>
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="{{ siteUrl }}">
                    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="magoon signs">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-nav">
            <a href="#" class="opener"><span>Menu</span></a>
            <nav id="nav">
                {# get menu items #}
                {% set pageItems = craft.entries.section('services').level('<= 2') %}
                {# % set pageItems = craft.entries.level('<= 2') %# }

                {# Output the sub menu #}
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
                    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug('about').first %}
                    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>

                    {% nav page in pageItems %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ page.navigationUrlOverride ? page.navigationUrlOverride : page.url }}">
                            {% if page.navigationTitle %}{{ page.navigationTitle|nl2br }}{% else %}{{ page.title }}{% endif %}
                        </a>
                        {% ifchildren %}
                        <div class="drop">
                            <ul>
                                {% children %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        {% endifchildren %}
                    </li>
                    {% endnav %}
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug('testimonials').first %}
                        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug('contact').first %}
                        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                    {% set entry = craft.entries.slug('get-a-quote').first %}
                        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

footer.html:

```
    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="holder">
            <a href="#" class="badge">
                <img src="/images/img4.png" alt="image description">
            </a>
            <div class="wrap">
                <ul class="social-networks">
                    <li><a class="linkdin" href="#">linkedin</a></li>
                    <li><a class="facebook" href="#">facebook</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h2>{{ siteName }}</h2>
                <address>{{ companyInfo.address }}</address>
                <a class="tel-link" href="tel:{{ companyInfo.phoneNumberLink }}">{{ companyInfo.phoneNumber }}</a>
                <span class="timings">
                    Open: <time datetime="2014-08-21">Mon.-Fri. 8:30am-4pm</time> Closed Daily from <time datetime="2014-08-21">12:00pm-1:00pm</time>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

head.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 " />

    {!-- META TITLE --}
    <title>
        {% if entry.metaTitle != '' %}
            {{entry.metaTitle}}
        {% else %}
            My Site
        {% endif %}
    </title>

    {!-- META DESCRPTION --}
    {% if entry.metaDescription != '' %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ entry.metaDescription }}">
    {% endif %}

    {!-- META KEYWORDS --}
    {% if entry.metaKeywords != '' %}
        <meta name="keywords" content="{{ entry.metaKeywords }}">
    {% endif %}

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vast+Shadow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/ie.js"></script><![endif]-->
    {% block css_wufoo %}{% endblock %}
    {% block css_fancybox %}{% endblock %}

</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates you're trying to use a Twig filter that [doesn't](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html) [exist](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters) in your 404 template at line 4.

Maybe you've got a plugin that added it's own filter, but you don't have the plugin installed or enabled?

**Update:**

Based on the follow up comments, the error message is very misleading and not sure where it is coming from.  The 404 template doesn't have an `entry` variable defined, so the solution is to wrap any references to it in:

```
{% if entry is defined %}
    {{ entry.metaTitle }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Brad. I think it's the `entry` tags causing issue. Any idea how to fix so that I can use those tags in head? I added code to original post for your reference.

Comment: Is that code from your `_layout.html` template?

Comment: Ya...I'm embedding the head in the `_layout.html`. Added to original post as well.

Comment: Might as well post global/head, global/header and global/footer, too. :)

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: If you comment out the calls to `entry.metaTitle`, `entry.metaDescription` and `entry.metaKeywords` in `head.html` does the error go away?

Comment: Yes, when I remove that block from head it works.

Comment: Seems like a misleading error message, then. Try wrapping those calls in `{% if entry is defined %}{% endif %}` blocks.

Comment: Need to modify the meta stuff a bit, but it works! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Really weird... updated my answer in case anyone else runs across this.